# Disable auto-suggestions in individual input fields in Chrome based on history

Tags: html, google-chrome

On HTML inputs in Chrome, how can the autofill be disabled for individual fields?

See the image below to see the issue. I'm using the Date/Time dropdown for bootstrap (but this can be for any plugin)

Chrome seems to cache the previously entered input when the form is submitted. So when the user comes back to the page again, this creates a UX issue.

[image: Sample Image]

What I've tried so far,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control js-datetime-picker" autocomplete="new-field">

<input type="text" class="form-control js-datetime-picker" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" class="form-control js-datetime-picker" autocomplete="false">
```

How can the auto-suggestions be disabled for a single field (not the whole form)?

UPDATE:
Since posting, I've found out this is a bug (branded as a feature) on Chrome, and the discussion is ongoing. If anyone has a solution, without using additional hidden fields or Javascript, please share.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587466

Answer (score 2):

On the form parent of the input elements (add one if there isnt one already) add this `autocomplete='off'` and then on the inputs add `autocomplete='false'`.

And to answer your question, 'can individual fields be disabled without the whole form' Yes. But you would need to add another form onto the child element.

Cheers.

Comment: Tried that. Still seeing the same result. Using Chrome 73.0 on a Mac.

Comment: @shanecp hmmm. That is strange. Are you just using inspect element?

Comment: Yeah try that. And if clearing cache doesnt work, then use a different browser or redownload chrome.

Comment: Well, I'm sure clearing cache will make it go away. But that's not what I want to happen. I want to clear the auto-suggestion history only for a specific field, while not clearing any other cache. (Because we can't ask the users to clear the cache every time they fill a form)

Answer (score 1):

You can deactivate the autocomplete with `autocomplete="new-password"`

`autocomplete="off"` or `autocomplete="false"` is not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

autocomplete="off" is the right solution. In your case I think there is some problem with Chrome browser. Update chrome or reinstall. That might solve your problem.